# Python - Don't Understand The Returned Results of This Concatenated Regex Pattern

Tags: python, regex, concatenation

I am a Python newb trying to get more understanding of regex. Just when I think I got a good grasp of the basics, something throws me - such as the following:

```
>>> import re

>>> text = "Some nouns like eggs egg bacon what a lovely donkey"
>>> noun_list = ['eggs', 'bacon', 'donkey', 'dog']
>>> noun_patt = r'\s' + '|'.join(noun_list) + r'\s'
>>> found = re.findall(noun_patt, text)
>>> found
[' eggs', 'bacon', 'donkey']
```

Since I set the regex pattern to find `'whitespace' + 'pipe joined list of nouns' + 'whitespace'` - how come:

`' eggs'` was found with a space before it and not after it?
`'bacon'` was found with no spaces either side of it?
`'donkey'` was found with no spaces either side of it and the fact there is no whitespace after it?

The result I was expecting: `[' eggs ', ' bacon ']`

I am using Python 2.7

Comment: When you have a problem like this, it really helps to print out `noun_patt` and make sure it's what you think it is…

Comment: @abarnert Hadn't though of that, that is a majorly useful piece of advice - cheers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You misunderstand the pattern. There is no group around the joint list of nouns, so the first `\s` is part of the `eggs` option, the `bacon` and `donkey` options have no spaces, and the `dog` option includes the final `\s` meta character .

You want to put a group around the nouns to delimit what the `|` option applies to:

```
noun_patt = r'\s(?:{})\s'.format('|'.join(noun_list))
```

The non-capturing group here (`(?:...)`) puts a limit on what the `|` options apply *to*. The `\s` spaces are now outside of the group and are thus not part of the 4 choices.

You need to use a non-capturing group because if you were to use a regular (capturing) group `.findall()` would return just the noun, not the spaces.

Demo:

```
>>> text = "Some nouns like eggs egg bacon what a lovely donkey"
>>> import re
>>> text = "Some nouns like eggs egg bacon what a lovely donkey"
>>> noun_list = ['eggs', 'bacon', 'donkey', 'dog']
>>> noun_patt = r'\s(?:{})\s'.format('|'.join(noun_list))
>>> re.findall(noun_patt, text)
[' eggs ', ' bacon ']
```

Now both spaces are part of the output.

Comment: Thanks Martijn! I had to reread about 10 times for my newbie brain to process, but now I get how the new code works. So the parenthesis isolates the joined nouns, and now we get "whitespace, plus any of the matched nouns in the joined list, plus whitespace". And the `?:` inhibits the capturing function of the parenthesis. That's awesome. I love this place - thanks again.